# Pop out a marker from a markercluster layer

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have about 1000 markers on a city map. They are clustered with markercluster. Under the map there is a (filtered) list. If you click on a list element, the map should show and highlight the marker of the list element for you.

Question is, how should I pop out only one marker from the markercluster layer?

Now, I use clearLayers() and iterate over all the points and push them - except the highlighted - to an array, and that will be the list to the addLayers(). The highlighted icon will be added to the map directly. So, that one won't be clustered.

```js
showGroup = function (group, highlightId) {
        var marker,
            list = [],
            points = poiDataBase[group],
            highlightClass,
            highlightIcon;
        clusterGroup.clearLayers();
        $('.grouplist > li').remove();
        if(highlighted) {
            map.removeLayer(highlighted);
        }

        $.each(points, function(k,v) {
            if(v.id != highlightId) {
                marker = L.marker([v.coord1, v.coord2], {id: v.id})
                    .bindPopup(v.popup)
                    .on('click', function() {
                        map.setView(L.latLng(v.coord1, v.coord2), map.getZoom(), {animate: true, duration: 0.5});
                        showGroup (group, v.id);
                    });
                list.push(marker);
                highlightClass = '';
            } else {
                highlightIcon = new L.Icon.Default({iconUrl: 'marker-icon-red.png'});
                marker = L.marker([v.coord1, v.coord2], {id: v.id, icon: highlightIcon})
                    .bindPopup(v.popup)
                    .on('click', function() {
                        map.setView(L.latLng(v.coord1, v.coord2), map.getZoom(), {animate: true, duration: 0.5});
                        showGroup (group, v.id);
                    });
                highlighted = marker.addTo(map);
                highlighted.openPopup();
                highlightClass = ' highlighted';
            }

            $('<li>')
                .text(v.name)
                .data({pinid: v.id, coord1: v.coord1, coord2: v.coord2})
                .attr({class: 'listitem-' + v.id + highlightClass})
                .on('click', function(){
                    map.setView(L.latLng($(this).data('coord1'), $(this).data('coord2')), map.getZoom(), {animate: true, duration: 0.5});
                    showGroup(group, $(this).data('pinid'));
                })
                .appendTo($('.grouplist'));
        });
        clusterGroup.addLayers(list);
    };
```

It works, but the iteration takes extra time and I hope there is an other way than touch the 1000 points on each highlight process.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have not found a solution already, you might be interested in [`clusterGroup.zoomToShowLayer(marker, callback)`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#other-group-methods) method.

It will pan and zoom the map as necessary, until the given marker is visible, possibly spiderfying the cluster group.

The behaviour is slightly different from what you have implemented, since it does not "extract" the marker from the group, but just adjusts the map view until the cluster group naturally splits the markers and the given marker becomes visible.